# Python: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None Message:

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

So i have been facing this problem in my python projects; whenever a javascript alert appears on my page(while working on the python CLI interpreter for ubuntu linux), every other instruction statement throws me this error

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
>   Message:

i mean even simple instructions such as browser.current_url as well as complex ones too.

if i try to switch to the alert and accept it using

> browser.switch_to.alert.accept()

this error comes up:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: No modal dialog is currently open

i usually end up closing the browser and restarting the test all over again. This is stressful.

i am using ubuntu linux 16.04 LTS + python 2.7 + selenium **version** = '3.4.3'

Comment: from where did you download this `selenium version = '3.4.3'`

Comment: hello, i used the pip command to install selenium. thanks

Comment: 3.13.0 is latest we have.

Comment: i just updated mine, still the same problem

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of the alert ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NkwQRI2

Comment: No that's an error , I am asking about alert screen shot

Answer (score 1):

Suspect it is because the alert is not immediately displayed and the switch alert is done quicker than the alert being displayed, you will end up having a NoAlertPresentException.

Perhaps you can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

...

```
browser.find_element_by_id('show-alert').click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present(), 'Timed out waiting for alerts to appear')
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Timeout and No Alert Appearing")
```